# Z3 Python API - when will it be available

Tags: api, z3

In the [Z3-Python tutorial](http://rise4fun.com/z3py/tutorialcontent/guide#h212), it is stated that in order to use Z3 locally with Python, one needs yo use the Python library in the Z3 release. However, my installation of the latest version (3.2) didn't contain such a folder. I imagine that this means that the folder exists on 4.0 . Does anyone know when is it supposed to be released?

Answer (score 1):

Z3 Python (Z3Py) is part of Z3 4.0. It will be released very soon.
If you need we can send you a pre-release version.

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime I'll wait.